# Why does variable in struct instance change after running function pointer defined in separate file

Tags: c, struct

This is really weird.

I have a struct with `int` variable `a` = 0 defined in a `Manager.h` file, instantiated in `Manager.c`.  The manager runs a function pointer during execution time, defined in `main.c`.  However, after running, `a` = 10.

Anyone knows why this is so?  To illustrate:

```
**Manager.h**

struct Manager {
    uint32_t a;
};

runFunction (void (* handler)());


**Manager.c**

struct Manager * manager = calloc(sizeof(struct Manager));

// ... 

**main.c**

void someFn() {
    // do stuff...
}

int main() {
    runFunction(someFn);
    // and manager->a becomes 10.  Previously, it was initialized to 0.
}
```

Comment: Please show a minimal and compilable test case.

Comment: `calloc()` with just one argument?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing misses one important point: it most likely didn't transport the error.